# Win32Exception StandardPrintController OnStartPrint

Tags: .net, wcf, printing, windows-services

I have a hosted service inside a Windows Service, this service is in charge of printing certain info I send.

So while debugging the error won't happen, I have to start my VS as an Administrator.

But in Production when I call .Print() I get the message "The system cannot find the file specified" and my stacktrace says:

at System.Windows.Forms.PrintControllerWithStatusDialog.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)

at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)

at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()

So far from what I have read is this is caused by a permission issue.

I already put my Windows Service as a Full Trust on its properties. I also added a manifest file on the assembly that is hosting the service.

The printer is valid and I'm able to print from any other program(Word,Excel). I also checked "Allow to interact with the desktop" and restarted the service.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using ClickOnce to generate the output by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you specifying an account on the service's LogOn tab? You probably need to provide an account that can access the printer normally. More details in our [Windows Services FAQ](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService).